# getaddressesbyaccount RPC alternative?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

I'm using Bitcoin Core v0.15.1. when I use `getaddressesbyaccount` in the debug console I can see the "account" is DEPRECATED. in fact all methods that uses "account" mark this parameter as DEPRECATED.

I realize that the whole "Accounts" feature is being deprecated, but 
there is no getaddressesby**label**.

How can I replace this method to get the address by the label? what does DEPRECATED means for future versions? will the **parameter** be ignored or removed or will the whole `getaddressesbyaccount` be removed?

in fact I'm not sure how to handle other methods with "account" parameter. this label is essential to my application. (I want to lookup address by a unique label/id I will give for each user that uses *my* wallet).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I realize that the whole "Accounts" feature is being deprecated, but there is no getaddressesbylabel.

It looks like there actually will be a `getaddressesbylabel` API call in a future version. Along with a handful of other methods that replace the accounts feature. [Check out this PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7729/files?diff=unified#diff-df7d84ff2f53fcb2a0dc15a3a51e55ceR3216).

> what does DEPRECATED means for future versions? will the parameter be ignored or removed or will the whole getaddressesbyaccount be removed?

When a feature is deprecated it will usually stick around for a while reporting that it will be removed in future versions of the software.

Answer (score 0):

it's not preferred to use Accounts in any future projects.

So far you can use as an alternative `getaccount` and `getbalance` RPC call.

The getaccount RPC returns the name of the account associated with the given address.

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet getaccount mjSk1Ny9spzU2fouzYgLqGUD8U41iR35QN
```

The getbalance RPC gets the balance in decimal bitcoins across all accounts or for a particular account.

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet getbalance "test1" 1 true
```

Parameter #1—an account name

Parameter #2—the minimum number of confirmations

Parameter #3—whether to include watch-only addresses